# How to clear the entered text in flutter integration test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

In flutter integration test, we generally enter the text by

`await tester.enterText(find.byKey(ValueKey(key)), value);`

But can anybody help me in clearing the entered text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation:

> Give the text input widget specified by finder the focus and **replace its content** with text...

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/enterText.html

you should be able to clear input text with:

```
await tester.enterText(find.byKey(ValueKey(key)), '');
```